# EF code first specify relationship table for a navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am new to EF code first and am trying to force an ICollection navigation property to use a specific relationship table I've manually created for mapping the entities.

The reason I am forced to do it is that I have a TenantId column on all my tables. Is this somehow possible?

```
[Table("Tenants")]
public class Tenant
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // This should use ContactAddressesForTenants table
    public virtual ICollection<Address> ContactAddresses {get; set;}

}

[Table("BusinessProfiles")]
public class BusinessProfile
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Tenant")]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    // This should use the AddressesForBusinessProfiles table
    public virtual ICollection<Address> ProfileAddresses { get; set; }
}

[Table("Addresses")]
public class Address
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Tenant")]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContactAddressesForTenants")]
public class ContactAddressForTenant
{
    [ForeignKey("Tenant")]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address {get; set;}
}

[Table("AddressesForBusinessProfiles")]
public class AddressForBusinessProfile
{
    [ForeignKey("BusinessProfile")]
    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Address")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual BusinessProfile BusinessProfile { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly.
You can try changing this in your model.

Where it is:

```
// This should use ContactAddressesForTenants table
public virtual ICollection<Address> ContactAddresses {get; set;}
// This should use the AddressesForBusinessProfiles table
public virtual ICollection<Address> ProfileAddresses { get; set; }
```

Change to:

```
public virtual ICollection<ContactAddressForTenant> ContactAddresses {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<AddressForBusinessProfile> ProfileAddresses { get; set; }
```